# JSON File: Count Unique Words Instead of Single Letters with Python

Tags: python, json, text, nlp

For a current research project, I am planning to count the unique words for a specific object within a JSON file. The code is however just counting single letters within the first line of the file object `"Text_Main"`.

The code works with full words if not inlcuding the `text = data[0]["Text Main"]` JSON object specification. Is there any smart tweak to have the code count the words instead of letters?

Output as it is currently showing (summary):

[image: ![enter image description here]

The JSON file has the following structure:

```
[
{"Stock Symbol":"A",
"Date":"05/11/2017",
"Text Main":"I have been working",
"Text Pro":"Text sample 2",
"Text Con":"Text sample 3"}
]
```

And the corresponding code looks like this:

```
# Import relevant libraries
import string
import json
import csv
import textblob

# Open JSON file and slice by object
file = open("Glassdoor_A.json", "r")
data = json.load(file)
text = data[0]["Text Main"]

# Create an empty dictionary
d = dict()

# Loop through each line of the file
for line in text:
    # Remove the leading spaces and newline character
    line = line.strip()

    # Convert the characters in line to
    # lowercase to avoid case mismatch
    line = line.lower()

    # Remove the punctuation marks from the line
    line = line.translate(line.maketrans("", "", string.punctuation))

    # Split the line into words
    words = line.split(" ")

    # Iterate over each word in line
    for word in words:
        # Check if the word is already in dictionary
        if word in d:
            # Increment count of word by 1
            d[word] = d[word] + 1
        else:
            # Add the word to dictionary with count 1
            d[word] = 1

# Print the contents of dictionary
for key in list(d.keys()):
    print(key, ":", d[key])

# Save results as CSV
with open('Glassdoor_A.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(["Word", "Occurrences"])
    writer.writerows([key, d[key])
```

Comment: I think your `text` variable is a string not a list of strings as you loop through it.

Comment: Thanks, that worked to get words instead of letters as result. However, the code is still just considering the first line of the JSON file. Is there anything I can amend to have all lines read/considered?

Comment: Well you only take `data[0]`, which is only the first line, if I understood what you mean. You could loop through data with a for loop.

Comment: Yup I added `data[0]` as I'm otherwise getting the following notifcation `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`. How would you loop the part given this background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you should loop through your `data`, taking each object (I called it `row`), taking its data element `Text Main` and do the rest of your processing.

```
# your importing code, etc...

# processing:
for row in data:
    line = row['Text Main']
    # Remove the leading spaces and newline character
    line = line.strip()

    # Convert the characters in line to
    # lowercase to avoid case mismatch
    line = line.lower()

    # Remove the punctuation marks from the line
    line = line.translate(line.maketrans("", "", string.punctuation))

    # Split the line into words
    words = line.split(" ")

    # Iterate over each word in line
    for word in words:
        # Check if the word is already in dictionary
        if word in d:
            # Increment count of word by 1
            d[word] = d[word] + 1
        else:
            # Add the word to dictionary with count 1
            d[word] = 1
```